# Volume using triple Integrals, cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate the volume of a solid with $z+1\ge x^2+y^2$ and $3\left(z-1\right)\le -\left(x^2+y^2\right)$. After cylindrical coordinates 
x=rcosϕ, y=rsinϕ
I got $r^2-1\le z$, and $z\le \frac{\left(3-r^2\right)}{3}$ , so $r^2-1\le z\le \frac{\left(3-r^2\right)}{3}$.
Then $r^2-1\le \frac{\left(3-r^2\right)}{3}$  ==> $0\le r\le 1$, $0\le \phi \le 2\pi $. After calculating the integral I got $\frac{4\pi }{3}$, which doesn't check the answer considered correct by the one who made the exercise, which is $\frac{3\pi }{2}$. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Or could that answer be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You could maybe show us your integral, and how you solved it.

Comment: $\int _0^1\int _0^{2\pi }\:\:\int _{r^2-1}^{\frac{\left(3-r^2\right)}{3}}\:r\:dzd\sigma dr$

Comment: I'm sure it's 4*pi/3, because I even used wolfram alpha to check it.

Comment: The problem I think can only be with the bounds.

Comment: What is $d\sigma$? Do you mean $d\phi$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is what I meant.

Comment: Ok, I get $\dfrac{4\pi}{3}$ too. I'll upvote the question and we'll just have to wait :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $r^2-1=1-\frac{r^2}{3}\implies r^2=\frac{3}{2}\implies r=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$,

$V=\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}\int_{r^2-1}^{1-\frac{r^2}{3}} r\;dz dr d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}\left(2r-\frac{4}{3}r^3\right)\;dr d\theta$

$\displaystyle\;\;=\int_0^{2\pi}\left[r^2-\frac{1}{3}r^4\right]_0^{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}=2\pi\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3}{4}\right)=\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I made such a mistake...I forgot to multiply the 1 from $r^2-1$ with the denominator of $\frac{\left(3-r^2\right)}{3}$, when I equaled them... Thanks for opening my eyes.